# Form keyDown not working?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.Control Then
        MessageBox.Show("aaaa")
    End If
End Sub
```

As you can see, my form will check for when the control key is pressed down.
But it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Is the cursor over any other UI element (label, button etc.) when you press the Ctrl key?

Comment: No, I believe I have my cursor on a free space.

Comment: Just checking, but see wageoghe's answer. I *always* forget this too.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I am not near a computer now so I can't test this, but when I have wanted to get key events on a form before, I would set Form1.KeyPreview to True (or something similar).

Comment: Umm, I don't think I can set Form1.KeyPreview to true... there's no option.

Comment: I'm surprised it doesn't exist. See this MSDN link about it:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Ah! I used Form1 instead of Me. Sorry. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

That works fine.  I assume you have other controls in your form.  One of them will get the focus, never the form.  Keyboard input only goes to the control with the focus.

You can set the form's KeyPreview property to True.  The Winforms' way is to override the ProcessCmdKey() method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set **KeyPreview** to true when loading the form, it should work then

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.KeyPreview = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    MsgBox(e.KeyChar)
End Sub
```