# Form keyPress help

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

first of all, I needed a way to know when the control key was down, and here's the link: [Form keyDown not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532279/form-keydown-not-working)

Thanks to them I got it working. But I noticed that was not my ultimate objective!
Instead of checking for the control key on keyDown, I want to check for it on keyPress. But apparently I can't use

```
    If e.Control Then

    End If
```

On the

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyPress

End Sub
```

Method.

Any ideas? I also want to check for when the key is no longer pressed...

---

New problem:

```
 Private Sub controlTick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        If Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Control Then
            controlActivated = True
            PictureBox2.Invalidate()
        End If
        If Control.ModifierKeys <> Keys.Control Then
            controlActivated = False
            PictureBox2.Invalidate()
        End If
        Label1.Text = controlActivated
    End Sub
```

That is inside a timer. For some reason it is always "False" unless I click somewhere with the control key pressed...

Comment: It is probably better to just say what you are trying to achieve as well as what you have tried to do it. I'm not sure from what you have written that you understand the key events (no pun intended), try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx There are 'lower' level windows message events you can filter on too. You can also get the state of a key by asking directly though you may have to pinvoke http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getasynckeystate

Answer (score 1):

By the time you get the KeyPress event, which you won't when the form has any controls, the Control key state is already applied to the pressed key.  So you'll get, say, Ctrl+V:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = ChrW(22) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Ctrl+V pressed")
    End If
End Sub
```

Ctrl+A = 1, etcetera, through Ctrl+Z = 26.  This is *very* likely what you want to do, you could also use the Control.ModifierKeys property:

```
    If Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.Control Then
        MessageBox.Show("Control key pressed")
    End If
```

Beware that many keys don't generate a KeyPressed event, like Ctrl+F1.  KeyDown is required to test them.

---

You should use Control.ModifierKeys in whatever operation that should be affected by whether or not the control key is down.  This timer's Tick event handler works fine:

```
Private Sub timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim controlActivated As Boolean
    If (Control.ModifierKeys And Keys.Control) = Keys.Control Then
        controlActivated = True
    End If
    Label1.Text = controlActivated.ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: All I need is to know whenever the control key (*only* the control key) is being pressed. You see, my user clicks on the interface a lot, and I want to create a different effect if the user has the control key down.

Comment: Use Control.ModifierKeys in whatever code that is affected by whether or not the key is down.  Do *not* use the KeyPress event.

Comment: Thanks! But now I got a little problem... edited the question's bottom.

Comment: I'll give this one more shot, post updated.  Good luck with it.

Comment: I wonder... is this correct for checking if the control key is NOT being pressed? *If Control.ModifierKeys <> Keys.Control*

Comment: Do you think it might be because I am using Parallels Desktop on Mac OSX to run Windows 7 and it might be mapping the control key incorrectly? I will go check on a purely windows PC and get back to you later.